# Qt Mkdir with a environment variable

Tags: qt

```
QDir *temp = new QDir("%USERPROFILE%");
bool ok = temp->mkdir("abc");
```

and it does not work.

Comment: Get the value of the variable with `getenv`. Part of `cstdlib.h` header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For portable Qt code, use static method  [QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qprocessenvironment.html#systemEnvironment):

```
QProcessEnvironment env(QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment());
QDir *temp = new QDir(env.value("USERPROFILE")); // returns empty string for unset variable
bool ok = temp->mkdir("abc");
```

Alternative, as suggested in a comment of the actual question, you can also use

```
#include <cstdio>

QString envValue(QString::fromLocal8bit(::getenv("USERPROFILE"))); // standard, yet deprecated in Windows...
```

I'd prefer using the first alternative, letting Qt take care of character encoding stuff. If you want to use non-Qt functions, I think in Windows you should use [getenv_s or _wgetenv_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb2sfw2z.aspx) to do this "properly".

Comment: There's also qgetenv(), but that doesn't handle encoding either.